# Image links are broken after uploading wordpress site from localhost to live server by using filezilla.

Tags: php, wordpress, filezilla

I just uploaded a wordpress site using filezilla to a live server. Everything is ok except for the images. All image links are broken. I then reuploaded the whole upload folder but nothing changed. I also checked the file and folder permissions set to the upload folder and found it to be 777. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**First, make a backup of your website (files and database)**

Then, install [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cm-on-demand-search-and-replace/).
After installing the plugin, look for "Tools > Search & Replace" in the Wordpress admin menu.

In the "Search for" form, enter localhost/127.0.0.1. In the "Replace with" form, enter your new domainname.

Comment: I thought changing site url would do the job. Won't it?

Comment: I do believe it would, but nothing ever goes as it should :)

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar kind of issue when i hosted my wordpress website from localhost to live url.. The images were not loading since all of them were having localhost links..

So I did the following to solve the issue:-

1. Opened the database and edited table wp_options - set the 'siteurl' and 'home' rows value to your live server URL.
2. Open your wordpress panel and install plugin - [Velvet](https://wordpress.org/plugins/velvet-blues-update-urls/) and activate it.
3. Go to tools section of wordpress -> click "update urls", and the plugin page will open.
4. Enter your old url (it may be your localhost, or any old domain where your site was previously hosted) and new url (your live server URL).
5. Check all the checkboxes below it, and hit the "Update URLs NOW" button.
6. *Optional:* If you used elementor to develop some of your pages, go to Elementor section of wordpress -> Tools -> "Replace url" tab, and repeat step 4 instructions here.

After doing this, 95% of the images of my site were fixed, but however logo and slider images were still not fixed.. So for that I had to go to "customize theme" option and re-select the logo and slider images..

Done.

Answer (score -1):

Give website name:

Have you update permalink??

Comment: where to change them all at a time?